# Twilio - A 'From' phone is required (aiohttp)

Tags: twilio

I tried over and over again to get this to work but it always returns with

`{'code': 21603, 'message': "A 'From' phone number is required.", 'more_info': 'https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21603', 'status': 400}`

Could someone please help?

My code:

```
    import asyncio, aiohttp

    async def main():
        auth = aiohttp.BasicAuth(login="[sid]", password="[token]")
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(auth=auth) as session:
            async with session.post("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/[sid]/Messages.json", params={"Body": "Test", "From": "[valid phone number]", "To": "[valid phone number]"}) as resp:
                print(await resp.json())

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `data=payload`, change your code to something like this:

---

```
import asyncio, aiohttp

async def main():
    payload = {"Body": "Test", "From": "[valid phone number]", "To": "[valid phone number]"}
    auth = aiohttp.BasicAuth(login="[sid]", password="[token]")
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(auth=auth) as session:
        async with session.post("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/[sid]/Messages.json", data=payload) as resp:
            print(await resp.json())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

---

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize that it was supposed to be `data` instead of `params` (in the docs it said that they were supposed to be parameters).